# Unable to get AWS Glue ETL logs after a certain point: What's wrong?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, etl, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I have created a ETL job using AWS Glue, I'm unable to get the logs after 3,4 lines of code.
The job has IAM role with **Administrator Access**
Type of ETL Job - Spark
Glue Version -  3.0, Supports Spark 3.1, Scala 2 & python 3
Following is the code snippet.

```
def main():
    print("inside main")
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    glue_client = session.client('glue')
    workflow_name = "xyz"
    workflow_run_id = "abvacsdsdacsdxxxxyxxxzzz"
    print("before workflow_args")
    print('Test')
    print(glue_client)
    **get_workflow_run = glue_client.get_workflow_run(Name=workflow_name, RunId=workflow_run_id)**
    print("after workflow_args")
    print(get_workflow_run)
```

OUTPUT on CloudWatch Console:

> **2023-05-24 06:18:59,996 main WARN JNDI lookup class is not available because this JRE does not support JNDI. JNDI string lookups will not
> be available, continuing configuration.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:173)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:211)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:232)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.newCheckedInstanceOf(Loader.java:301)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.(Interpolator.java:95)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.(AbstractConfiguration.java:114)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.(DefaultConfiguration.java:55)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build(PatternLayout.java:430)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(PatternLayout.java:324)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder.(ConsoleAppender.java:121)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.newBuilder(ConsoleAppender.java:111)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.createBuilder(PluginBuilder.java:158)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:813)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:753)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:745)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:389)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:169)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:181)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:446)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:520)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:536)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:214)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:146)
> at
> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:597)
> at
> org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsConfigUtils.(MetricsConfigUtils.java:12)
> at
> org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsProxyInfo.fromConfig(MetricsProxyInfo.java:17)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.cloudwatch.CloudWatchLogsAppenderCommon.(CloudWatchLogsAppenderCommon.java:62)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.cloudwatch.CloudWatchLogsAppenderCommon$CloudWatchLogsAppenderCommonBuilder.build(CloudWatchLogsAppenderCommon.java:79)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.cloudwatch.CloudWatchAppender.activateOptions(CloudWatchAppender.java:73)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
> at
> org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
> at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.(LogManager.java:127) at
> org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
> at
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
> at
> org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
> at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150) at
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
> at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
> at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357) at
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383) at
> org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.(JavaUtils.java:41) at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigHelpers$.byteFromString(ConfigBuilder.scala:67)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder.$anonfun$bytesConf$1(ConfigBuilder.scala:259)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigBuilder.$anonfun$bytesConf$1$adapted(ConfigBuilder.scala:259)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.$anonfun$transform$1(ConfigBuilder.scala:101)
> at
> org.apache.spark.internal.config.TypedConfigBuilder.createWithDefault(ConfigBuilder.scala:144)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.(package.scala:345)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.(package.scala)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala:654) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.$anonfun$loadFromSystemProperties$3(SparkConf.scala:76)
> at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:788)
> at
> scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:230)
> at
> scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:461)
> at
> scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:461)
> at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:787)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:75)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.(SparkConf.scala:70) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.(SparkConf.scala:59) at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.getSparkConf(ProcessLauncher.scala:41)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin.getSparkConf$(ProcessLauncher.scala:40)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.getSparkConf(ProcessLauncher.scala:90)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.(ProcessLauncher.scala:97)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.(ProcessLauncher.scala:90)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:29)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)
>
> 2023-05-24T11:49:00.000+05:30 2023-05-24 06:19:00,000 main INFO Log4j
> appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no
> log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support,
> please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib
> directory.
>
> 2023-05-24T11:49:09.753+05:30 inside main
>
> 2023-05-24T11:49:09.870+05:30 before workflow_args Test
> <botocore.client.Glue object at 0x7f864522ab90>**

ISSUE:

For some weird reason, I'm not getting output after the following line

```
print(glue_client)
```

I tried following:

1. Intentionally added mistakes to code so that error would generate and it would be thrown to CloudWatch.
2. Changed Glue Version.
3. Checked script through CloudShell, worked perfectly fine.